# how to select row by dynamical columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to select rows from a DataFrame by dynamic column values, but I don't know how should I write the code to dynamically generate the condition, please help, for example:

I have no idea how to generate the dynamical condition.

```
df = data[(self.data[col1]==1) |  (self.data[col2]==2)]
```

it is ok if I know there are 2 columns, but the problem is that the actual columns are decided on the fly. how should i used for ... in .. to generator proper condition like this `(self.data[col1]==1) | (self.data[col2]==2) |`

Comment: What do you mean on the fly? You are the columns in the same index position regardless of name?

Comment: the number of columns will be decided at the code running, the columns is a list of dictionary, column name is the dict key, column value is  the dict value

Comment: Is the condition **always** `|`?

Answer (score 1):

This is `np.logical_or.reduce` since you have a dictionary that you can iterate over, and the condition is `|`:

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, (100, 10)), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'h': 8, 'f': 4}
```

#### Code:

```
mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df[k] == v for k,v in d.items()])
df1 = df.loc[mask]
```

#### Output `df1`:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
1   6  3  5  3  5  8  8  2  8  1
3   8  4  7  6  2  4  5  9  2  5
4   1  4  3  1  5  3  8  8  9  7
5   4  8  8  5  6  4  7  9  1  3
6   8  8  8  4  1  9  8  8  2  2
12  2  3  2  6  5  1  8  9  6  8
13  1  4  2  5  5  7  9  9  3  8
22  7  8  1  4  1  4  5  8  6  4
...
```

If need multiple checks for the same column, consider lists as values: `d = {'a': [1,3], 'b': [3]}` and instead check `df[k].isin(v)`